# Do 'multiply defined labels' refer to the last labelled item?

Tags: equations, labels

In my work as LaTeX typesetter I often deal `with multiply defined` labels warnings. Most of them are about equations.

My question is, do the `\ref` command "always" refer to the last labelled item? In my experience it is so, but I'd like to know if there are cases (e.g. settings o packages) in which this is not true.

E.g. if I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Equation~(\ref{eq1})
\begin{equation}
1 +1 =3
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
Equation~(\ref{eq1})
\begin{equation}
2 +2 =5
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

both refs refers to the last equation.

**Note.** We always ask the author(s) to check about the warning but my company policy is to remove the warning "before" sending the proofs. I'm searching for a "scripting" way to manage these cases, commenting all the multiply defined labels except for the last one, yet I need to know if this is a safe approach.

Comment: The `\ref{somelabel}` command refers to a counter labelled `somelabel`. So if you have this message, it means you have some equations with the same label. B.t.w., for equations, you should use `\eqef` if you want to have the parentheses around the equation number.

Comment: If one of the label is referenced you can't know which one the author meant. As a typesetter you really shouldn't delete one of the \labels. Make a clear note and let the author sort this out.

Comment: I'm not the guy that makes the rules in my company and, yes, we always ask the authors to check. (See the comment to egreg answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `.aux` file, then you see

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
\newlabel{eq1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{eq1}{{2}{1}}
```

As part of `\begin{document}`, LaTeX reads the `.aux` file (as produced in the previous run) and the command `\newlabel{eq1}{{1}{1}}` essentially does

```
\global\@namedef{r@eq1}{{1}{1}}
```

which is then overridden by the later

```
\global\@namedef{r@eq1}{{2}{1}}
```

with the effect that `\ref{eq1}` will point to equation 2, because `\ref{eq1}` checks for the macro `\r@eq1` (produced with `\csname`, so numbers are legal in it) to be defined and, in case, it uses the contents in the first brace pair from its replacement text (`\pageref` uses the second).

When `\end{document}` is processed, the `.aux` file produced in the current run is read in, but `\newlabel` does different things, among which checking whether the label has already appeared.

The solution is very simple: *never* duplicate labels. In case there are, you need to ask the author to fix them. Using the last one may not be the author’s intention.

Comment: I agree with you about "never duplicate labels", but I'm only a typesetter, not the author of the papers I work on. I know about the `.aux` file stuff but I need to know if some package or some sort of "`break-command`" within the document can change this behaviour.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi In my experience, duplicate labels usually stem from authors using a “template” or editor macros that automatically provide a `\label`. If the argument to `\newlabel` is clearly a dummy (empty, a bullet or whatnot), you can safely ignore it. Otherwise you, as the typesetter, cannot guess.

Comment: In my experience often this happens when authors copy and paste an equation. Let me explain. Of course we always ask a final check to the authors, but this is a "minor issue" and we can publish the paper in case we do not receive an answer. The guidelines tell me to refer to the received `.pdf` copy of the manuscript. I'm trying to understand if it is really necessary to look at this pdf or if I can safely keep the last `\label` command.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi No, you can't, in my opinion.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi -- i agree with egreg here.  it *is* necessary to check the pdf submitted by the author.  and the duplicate labels do not necessarily come from the most recent displays; in a book, they can sometimes be many chapters apart.  some authors are not careful to check their log for duplicates, so even a comparison with the author's pdf does not always give a reliable answer.  ask the author, providing as much information as possible about the conflict.  (credentials: i'm the author support person for the american math society.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think I've not been able to explain the question. Of course we always ask the author(s) for a final check providing all the information about the conflict. But sometimes him/they do not answer to our query so we publish the paper as it stands. In these cases the accepted manuscript is "the law" for us, so if there is a mistake is the author's fault. What I'm asking is, in these cases, do I need really to check the pdf? Is the last labelled item always the one latex refers to?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Yes, for the reason I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @egreg Ok. Thank you very much. I was not sure if some settings or packages could alter this behaviour.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi There is code on the site attempting at allowing duplicate labels (with different references, of course), but in this case the warning should not appear.